# Weighted Median bootstrap

Tags: r, median, statistics-bootstrap

Currently I am obtaining 95% CI on the median by using this

```
x<-rnorm(100)
        bootmed = apply(matrix(sample(x, rep=TRUE, 10^4*length(x)), nrow=10^4), 1, median)
    quantile(bootmed, c(.025, 0.975))[1]->a1
    quantile(bootmed, c(.025, 0.975))[2]->a2
```

the problem now is that i need to do this for a weighted Median. I use the `weightedMedian` function in the  `matrixStats` package: `matrixStats::weightedMedian`

so I do not only have x with the numbers but also y with the weights `(runif(100))` - so now I calculate

```
weightedMedian(x,runif(100))
```

but how does the equivalent for the above bootstrap go?

Comment: no idea from anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `...` argument of the `apply()` function allows you to pass optional arguments to your function. Alternatively, you can also define a custom function. Assuming that your median weights are identical for all rows, the answer to your question looks like this:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
M <- matrix(sample(x, rep=TRUE, 10^4*length(x)), nrow=10^4)

bootmed = apply(M, 1, weightedMedian, w=y)
# Or, alternatively..
bootmed = apply(M, 1, function(x) weightedMedian(x,y))
```